# Asp.net identity doesn't save data to database after deployment

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, owin-middleware

First of all, I am new to asp.net. I am facing a wired issue with my asp.net Web Api2 project.

My SQL Server is hosted in an Azure VM and I am using Owin middleware for authentication. These are the connection strings I using to connect to my database:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="data source=13.**.***.***;initial catalog=A***;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
    <add name="DatabaseEntities"  
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=13.**.***.***;initial catalog=A***;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now the problem is, when I register an user, in localhost, it works and I can see newly created in my database, but when I publish my app to azure web service, it creates new user successfully (I see status 200 OK on postman) but I don't see the user in the database.

Everything works as expected, I just don't see newly created user on my DB, its being saved somewhere else.

I've been looking for solutions for last 2 days, no luck yet. Anybody to help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: you need to post the code you are using to save your data to the database

Comment: I am not doing anything to save data to the database. I just change the connection string to point my SQL server and tables were generated by Asp.net Identity itself. I am using the built in AccountController to register users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the DBContext Connection string name. It might some thing different than what you are expecting.